# Det(AB)=0: what is the determinant of A and B

Tags: matrices, determinant

True or false.
If the determinant of AB is zero, then the determinant of A is zero or the determinant of B is zero.

I put true in my exam. After all det(A)det(B)=det(AB).

Why was I wrong? The answer is apparently is wrong.

Comment: What is exactly the statement you had in the exam -- and what is the exact answer provided in the solution?

Comment: True or False.
If det(AB)=0, then det(A)=0 or det(B)=0.
I put true. My teacher took of marks and wrote FALSE.

Comment: Just making sure, are all matrices assumed to be over a field?

Comment: Sorry Arthur, what do you mean by field?

Comment: Well, if you are dealing with matrices over something else than the reals, this could lead to this. Namely, a ring with non-zero elements $a,b$ such that $ab=0$: but that's a tad contrived.

Comment: Oh no, we restrict ourselves to R in our class.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible for $AB$ to be a square matrix but neither of $A$ nor $B$ is square, for example if $A$ is a $2 \times 3$ matrix and $B$ is a $3 \times 2$ matrix. In this case, it is possible that $\det(AB)$ will be zero, but the determinants of $A$ and $B$ are not defined.

It may be that this is why your answer was marked as incorrect. However, if it was specified that $A$ and $B$ be square, then your answer was correct (and so was your reasoning).

Comment: A bit misleading to ask if $det(A)=0$ when $A$ is not square.

Comment: Of course! How tricky. Thanks Clive.

Comment: @Wood: Almost as misleading as taking points off for a correct answer ;)

Comment: Yes, this must be why he took off points. He did not specify the sizes.

Comment: @yolo123: do you get to talk to your teacher? If so I think really the only sensible thing to do is to ask for a counter-example. If the example comes back as non-square matrices (hence with no determinant) then this is what the teacher intended. Don't say this to the teacher, but it's really a trick question since the statement that you're asked the truth or falsehood of is under-specified and hence ambiguous. It's naughty not to state what A and B when making a statement about their properties :-)

Comment: I would consider the following question equally devious: "true or false, det($A^T$) = det($A$)? ($A^T$ being the transpose)". "False, because if A is not square then neither matrix has a determinant."

Comment: Totally devious! :) Maybe I could snatch a few points? Although that would bug me at night...